# Is there a c++ compiler or add-on that supports builtin object serialization?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, compiler-construction

The biggest pain of using libraries like boost::serialization is that a method needs to be supplied to each class that enumerates its fields. It's easy to make a mistake or forget to keep this method updated.

It seems that object serialization could easily be automated if there was extra support from the compiler. I guess it would be a language extension, but not visible directly to the user, only through a library. Is there a project that does this for gcc or perhaps clang?

Comment: What, like javascript? Spit out C++ objects in JSON? It seems mostly possible with a source-code-reading tool actually.

Comment: Visual Studio C++ CLI extensions should support such features.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not for native types. IOW: C++ CLI doesn't support it. CLR does. But C++CLI is simply not C++. At all. It's CLR in /unsafe mode by default and a lot of (very very nice) C++ interop glue.

Answer (score 1):

Not really

Serialization isn't standardized in C++ (i.e. it's not in a standard library nor in a compiler). You'll need a special library.

Comment: You don't mention why such a library cannot be made. This is a rather unconvincing / unsatisfying answer then

Comment: It's just not standardized into C++ (yet). It can be done, boost::serialization like he mentioned is one solution. C++ just doesn't have serialization (yet) because things like lambdas and auto have had more priority.

Comment: Boost doesn't do this.  Also I didn't mention that.  And yes I use fusion for"reflection". That is the missing keyword, by the way

Comment: It does _not_ do "builtin object serialization" - cf. the question title